Quantum mechanics in the language of differential geometry
So I am currently studying differential geometry and start recognizing a lot of concepts familiar from physics in the toolset of manifolds, tangential bundles and vector fields. In particular, we can define a vector field $Q$ (in the set of all vector fields $\Gamma(TM)$) to be the map from some manifold $M$ to its tangential bundle $TM$. Then for any $Q,P \in \Gamma(TM)$ we define the Lie bracket $[Q,P] = Q(P)-P(Q)$. We say that $[Q,P] = 0$ if the underlying manifold is "flat" in a certain sense. This means that for some function $f$ defined on the manifold $M$, applying $P$ and then $Q$ is different then applying $Q$ and then $P$. Of course one immediately makes a connection to quantum mechanics. The key difference between QM and classical mechanics is that the Lie bracket of two operators is non-vanishing in quantum mechanics. This begs the following questions:

What is the underlying manifold $M$ on which quantum mechanics is defined? My naive guess is that this would be the Hilbert space (or some version of it), and therefore the points on this manifold would be the quantum mechanical states.
By applying the operators $Q$ and $P$ from the tangential bundle we want to check in which direction on the manifold a function of the states evolves. So what is this tangential bundle $TM$?
Finally, because $[Q,P]\neq 0$ on our quantum mechanical manifold $M$, then this manifold must be "curved" in some sense. In which sense is it curved? Does it then mean that the manifold used in classical mechanics (I am guessing this would be the phase space) is flat in the exact same sense? I.e., can I define a manifold for classical mechanics and then "curve" it to get a manifold where operators are non-commutating and thus describe a quantum mechanical system?

Additionally, is quantum mechanics ever treated in the language of differential geometry in physics circles? This whole Lie bracket construction kind of begs one to look at QM from this perspective but I've never really seen any talk of tangent spaces or manifolds in any QM lectures.

Sometimes forces (normally just gravity, but also the weak/strong/electromagnetic forces in the context of quantum mechanics treated with differential geometry) are treated as fictitious forces resulting from the curvature of gauge fields in the same way gravity is treated as a fictitious force resulting from the curvature of spacetime.. Does that count?

Some read this.

Beware: Just because you have learned about one hammer, that doesn't mean you have to use it on every nail you see.
Yes, the Lie bracket of vector fields is the same kind of structure as the commutator of linear operators on a vector space - both the vector fields and their bracket and the linear operators and their commutator are examples of Lie algebras. But that does not mean that everything that's a Lie algebra must be interpreted as the algebra of vector fields on some manifold.
For instance, the differential-geometric treatment of classical Hamiltonian mechanics conceives of phase space as a symplectic manifold and has the Poisson bracket as the bracket for the Lie algebra of classical observables (i.e. functions on phase space). The Poisson bracket is related to the Lie bracket of vector fields, but they are not the same and the Poisson bracket acts on functions, not vector fields.
So the basic assumption in the question that because the quantum mechanical commutator looks like a Lie bracket it must be related to some vector fields on some manifolds is not justified, that's not how it works. The state space of quantum mechanics is a Hilbert space, and the relevant Lie bracket is the commutator of linear operators on this space, not that of vector fields on some manifolds. Quantum mechanics is not classical mechanics.
That does not mean that the similarity noticed in the question is entirely accidental - canonical quantization can be understood as a heuristic procedure turning the Poisson bracket into the commutator, and there are quantization procedures that try to generalize this to arbitrary classical phase space manifolds. This is the main subject of the theory of geometric quantization, and typical expositions on it are heavy on the language of symplectic geometry. Nevertheless, as its output it still produces a quantum theory on a Hilbert space, not some arbitrary manifold.
A completely unrelated, but nevertheless geometric, line of thinking is the theory of non-commutative geometry attempting to give a geometric interpretation to quantum mechanics more in the vein of the thoughts in the question. However, it has definitely not found widespread adoption among physicists or mathematical physicists as the primary language of quantum mechanics.

"the relevant Lie bracket is the commutator of linear operators on this space, not that of vector fields on some manifolds" I don't understand how the latter cannot be seen as a formalization/abstraction of the former. Vector fields apply on a function to give another function exactly like linear operators act on states to give other states.  What is stopping us from taking the state space to be a manifold? I'm not necessarily saying this is a useful way to think about the state space but why is it incorrect?

@Hrach Vector fields on a manifold are linear operators when acting on the space of functions on the manifold, that's true. They are not linear operators on the manifold, even when that manifold is also a vector space.

Hmm, I think I see the issue. These vector fields act linearly on functions on the manifold which map to real numbers and there isn't any sense in which quantum states are similar to these functions. On the other hand, if we say the points on the manifold are the states then the operators are no longer linear when acting on these points.
